# Calculating with time (JS), time format as HHMM

Tags: javascript, time

I'm in a brain freeze here.

I have 2 times:

(int) 1815 (18:15) and (int) 1915 (19:15) and I want to calculate the amount of 15 minute blocks between them. (4). How can I approach this in a solid manner?

Comment: This is only about time, or it is also about Date and Time?

Comment: By storing them in an appropriate format in int. `18:15` should be - depending on your use case - something like `18*60+15 = 1095` in the int represenation and not `1815`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the minutes of every value and get the delta divided by a quarter hour.

```js
function getMin(t) {
    return Math.floor(t / 100) * 60 + t % 100;
}

var a = 1815,
    b = 1915,
    delta = Math.round((getMin(b) - getMin(a)) / 15);
    
console.log(delta);
```